# How to call a JS function from a nodejs c ++ extension

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

How to call a function inside a JS file from a nodejs c++ extension module?

I want to call this `test_function` function from a C++ function.

```
void CallJSFunc(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
   v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::Object> global_obj = isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global();
  v8::Local<v8::Value> value = global_obj->Get(
      v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), "test_function")
  );
  Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(value);
  Local<Value> arg1s[2];
  arg1s[0] = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "value1");
  arg1s[1] = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "value2");

   func->Call(global_obj, 2, arg1s);
}
```

```
function test_function(test_arg1, test_arg2) {
    var match = 0;
    if (test_arg1 === test_arg2) {
        match = 1;
    } else {
        match = 0;
    }
    return match;
}
```

The version of my NodeJS is: node-v10.9.0

Thank you for visiting this question.